# QRScanner: startActivityForResult throws ActivityNotFound exception

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, qr-code

In my app, I try to call an intent for a result but it is showing an "Activity not found exception".

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

mayby the scanner is not installed? try this:

```
if (checkpackage(context, "com.google.zxing.client.android")) {
        ((Activity) c).startActivityForResult(new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"), 0);
    } else {
        Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android");
        Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(marketUri);
        ((Activity) c).startActivity(marketIntent);
        Toast.makeText(c, "Es ist kein Barcodescanner installiert", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

public static boolean checkpackage(Context ctx, String PACKAGE_NAME) {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(PACKAGE_NAME, 0);
        return info != null;

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```